# Getting errors: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: directory, permissions

Runnings Anaconda on Windows 10. Getting these errors when trying to install any new package. Permission Denied / No such file or directory. Tried Removing the MAX_PATH Limitation but it is not working. What is the solution ?

WARNING: Error parsing requirements for pyqt5: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\abcxyz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5-5.12.3.dist-info\METADATA'

WARNING: Error parsing requirements for pyqtwebengine: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\abcxyz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQtWebEngine-5.12.1.dist-info\METADATA'

WARNING: Error parsing requirements for cookiecutter: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\abcxyz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter-1.7.2.dist-info\METADATA'

WARNING: Error parsing requirements for matplotlib: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\abcxyz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.3.4.dist-info\METADATA'

WARNING: Error parsing requirements for pandas: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\users\abcxyz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas-1.0.5.dist-info\METADATA'

WARNING: Error parsing requirements for qstylizer: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\abcxyz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qstylizer-0.1.10.dist-info\METADATA

Comment: Can anybody help on this ?